# Varios dispositivos conectados a un socket

Tags: javascript, php, socket, websocket

Soy nuevo usando sockets, websockets, workers etc... Nunca antes los usé.

Para practicar quisiera hacer alguna app simple algo más compleja que lo que hay por internet que solo son ejemplos muy básicos.

Había pensado en el juego del Bingo. Un servidor va diciendo números al azar y los clientes (no solo uno y en diferentes dispositivos), van captando esos números y van rellenando su respectiva cartilla según el número.

Estoy perdido en el tema y quizás sea más sencillo de lo que pensaba pero la verdad no sé.

Esto solo funciona para un cliente, necesito que cualquiera pueda conectarse sin que el otro cliente deje de recibir números.

Código Websocket:

```
// Importing the required modules
const WebSocketServer = require('ws');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const port = 8081
// Creating a new websocket server
const wss = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: port })


const wsSelected = []
// Creating connection using websocket
wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("Nuevo cliente!");

    setInterval(() => {
        ws.send(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
    }, 500)

    // sending message
    ws.on("message", data => {});

    // handling what to do when clients disconnects from server
    ws.on("close", () => {
        console.log("El cliente se ha disconconetado");
    });

    // handling client connection error
    ws.onerror = function () {
        console.log("Ha ocurrido algún error")
    }
});

console.log("El WebSocketServer está corriendo ene le puerto " + port);
```

Código cliente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BINGO</title>

</head>
<body class="bg-dark text-white">
    <h2>Número cantado: <span class="numero"></span></h2>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081")
        const type = "Quiero jugar al bingo!"

        ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
           ws.send(type)
        });

        ws.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            let data = JSON.parse(event.data)
            console.log(data)
            let numero = data
            $(`.numero`).text(numero)
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si buscas que tu pregunta no sea basada en opiniones, borra la última oración que has escrito, y pon el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Como te han indicado, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Ya he hecho lo que me has dicho.

Comment: Hola Carlos, precisamente las preguntas que piden recursos externos acaban cerradas por estar fuera de tema: En SOes se responden dudas concretas o se resuelven problemas/bugs de código expuestos. Podemos guiarte para que resuelvas tu problema por ti mismo

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que busco pero la peña me exige un código y no sé como realizar la pregunta, ya que tengo un código que funciona pero no como quiero que funcione... especifico que solo necesito orientación y me dicen que borre este comentario porque esto no es un foro y la verdad que no entiendo el punto. Favor que alguien me oriente!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé cómo estás cargando tu página, pero asumo que tienes un servidor web corriendo a la vez que ese código, algo como:

```javascript
const WS = require('ws');
const WS_PORT = 8081;

//código extra para servir la página index.html desde ./public/index.html
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port: ${PORT}`));
app.use(express.static('public'));

// ... tu código
```

Una vez aclarado esto, el problema es que estás generando un número aleatorio **para cada cliente** que se te conecta, cuando deberías tener un generador de números que mandase a todos los clientes conectados el mismo.

Te bastaría con guardar todas las conexiones que se abren y mandar a todas el mismo número. Por supuesto, debes eliminar de la lista las conexiones según se cierran.

Te dejo el código (ocultado, por si prefieres probar primero por tu lado) funcionando, realmente no necesitas muchos cambios. He probado a abrir a la vez la página en Firefox y en Chrome y ambos reciben a la vez el mismo número.

```js
const WS = require('ws');
const WS_PORT = 8081
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening , go to http://localhost:${PORT}`));
app.use(express.static('public'));


const wss = new WS.Server({ port: WS_PORT })

const wsSelected = new Set();
// Creating connection using websocket

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    //mandamos el mismo número a todos
    wsSelected.forEach(ws => 
        ws.send(randomNumber)
    )
}, 2000);

wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("Nuevo cliente!");
    
    //añadimos la conexión a nuestro conjunto
    wsSelected.add(ws);
    
    // sending message
    ws.on("message", data => {});

    // handling what to do when clients disconnects from server
    ws.on("close", () => {
        console.log("Un cliente se ha desconectado");
        wsSelected.delete(ws); //quitamos la conexión de nuestro conjunto
    });

    // handling client connection error
    ws.onerror = function () {
        console.log("Ha ocurrido algún error");
    }
});

console.log("El WebSocketServer está corriendo en el puerto " + WS_PORT);
```

**Nota**: estoy usando express para servir la página HTML, necesitarás añadirlo a tus dependencias: Ejecuta `npm install express --save` en el caso de que no lo estuvieras usando ya.

Comment: El script en el servidor está arrancado con NodeJS, lo pruebo y te hago saber.

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias por especificar lo del servidor pero no me ha hecho falta. He hecho los cambios comentados y listo, tengo ya dispositivos distintios recibiendo la misma info que es lo que quería!!